# Limit program's (Viber for Linux) access only to certain directory

Tags: access-control, selinux

Is it possible to limit programs' access only to certain directory, for example, to run [*Viber*](http://www.viber.com/products/linux/) on Fedora and force it to only be able to read under `/home/username/.local/share/viber/exchange` and no other directories?

I have managed to create and run *Viber* as another `user:group` (`viber:viber`). When I try to open from inside Viber files that belong to me or any other user, it can't read them. Goal achieved but partly. Now, I stumbled against another problem, which is *Viber* works only with messages and when I try to make a call, it says, that it can't find neither microphone nor speakers? It feels that I know why (I run X Server (GNOME) as myself and *Viber* as `viber:viber` (`user:group`) ) but I'm not sure how to let *viber* user to use microphone and speakers while running X server under my name?

May be, I need to add `viber` user to a certain group? Probably there are some workarounds with SELinux? If so could you provide proper policy example? :D

*Viber* seems to be great but it's not open-source and only God knows, what is on the source-code of that pre-compiled piece of software!

Answer (score 2):

#### Using `chroot`

Create a small *root directory* containing `/bin`, `/usr`, `/lib`, `/tmp` and so on (depending on your need), copy all your stuff into this *new root*, than run `chroot` into this directory.

`chroot` command is a very old Un*x tool, built exactly in this meaning.

You could *bind* directory in *container* by using `mount --bind`.

Have a look at `man chroot` and `man mount`!

Little try:

```
ldd /bin/bash 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff3e4b5000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f06290a1000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0628e9d000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0628b12000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f06292e8000)


sudo -s
```

**Warning, from there!**

```
mkdir /tmp/test/chrooted/lib64
cp -t /tmp/test/chrooted/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/{libc.so.6,libdl.so.2,libtinfo.so.5}
cp -t /tmp/test/chrooted/lib64 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 
chroot /tmp/test/chrooted
```

I'm jailed!

```
ls
bash: ls: command not found
```

There is no `ls` command in `/bin`!

#### Using `openvz` or `lxc`

Next step in *light virtualisation* is to run one of `openvz` or `lxc` (or other, maybe).

This tools do approx. same than `chroot`, but use *isolated kernel namespace*. This let you simulate network interfaces or other devices and some limitations around memory, cpu and other resources...

With this kind of *light virtualisation*, you could share directories in same manner than using `chroot`, by using `mount --bind` (or under `openvz` maybe using `mount -t simfs` could be usefull).

#### Strong virtualisation

Next you may use `kvm`, `xen` or other propretary virtalization software...

But from there, sharing directories implie some kind of *(pseudo) network service*...

Comment: I think, after re-reading your question, the simpliest way is to use `chroot`. Maybe one copy in each user's homedir. You could use *hardlinks* for that: see `cp -l`.

Comment: Thank you, F.Hauri! I was trying to do it before, but on Fedora it says: `chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory`?

Comment: You have to install a copy of `/bin/bash` in chrooted env, but you have copy used libraries too! Try the command `ldd /bin/bash` to see what's needed.

Comment: I tried that! I create a directory `/home/username/viber/chroot`, then under it, I created `bin`,`lib`,`home`,`var`,`etc`. Inside of `lib` I put those files that were output on `ldd` and inside of `bin` I put `bash`? Not sure why it's not working? What about owner permissions? What about cmd? Is it  `chroot /home/username/viber/chroot`? I still got that error? Do I run it as `root`? I did. What are permission settings should be on folders?

Comment: Be *very* careful **not** to run Viber as root (after chroot, you will be root unless you change user). Since Viber is a presumably a GUI application, it will also have access to all other visisble windows by default. For the "easiest" separation using virtualization software, I would personally use QEMU (KVM), but others like VirtualBox should work fine too. In other cases, I try to use [AppArmor](http://wiki.apparmor.net/).

Comment: @Lekensteyn  You're right! It's better to copy `/etc/passwd`, `su` and needed stuff for doing `su $USER` once chrooted! This could be scripted.

Comment: What is the big difference between doing what I have already done (created viber:viber user/group), if Viber can't access mic and speakers? How to access hardware while runnind X server as another user?

Comment: You could not use any device if already in use... This seem to be another problem! Please ask another question!

Comment: It's not in use. Like I have written in my question I have already managed to limit Viber's access to the other folders. Using `chroot` is just an alternative! Thank you for providing an example, but it's crucial for me to let Viber use 'my' mic and speakers, while running as another user. Please look what I have written in my question: `I'm not sure how to let viber user to use microphone and speakers while running X server under my name?`

Comment: Alright, so be it, I will ask another question! Thanks for your help anyway! :)